# Android Circular Progress Bar (Material Design) change color

Tags: android

I need to change the color of the ProgressBar element in a Lollipop (API 21) app.
To be more clear, i mean, for example, to the Youtube mobile app circular progress bar. I need, for example, to make the color of the progress bar red.
I've seen over the internet some examples that use a drawable.xml file but all of theme modify also the animation style of the progress bar. I'd like to maintain the Lollipop/Material Design default animation.

Thanks to all.

Comment: https://github.com/grmaciel/two-level-circular-progress-bar

Answer (score 6):

Use "src_in" for the indeterminateTintMode and set indeterminateTint to the color you wish to change the progress bar to.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarSpinner"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/red"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I just put it in the design view using the following proprieties in Android Studio. Works for me anyway

Design
indeterminateTint = your color
indeterminateTintMode = multiply

Text

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarSpinner"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/accent_material_dark"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="multiply"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setIndicatorColor` or `app:indicatorColor`